# Prestashop 1.6 smarty override {include file=....} not overrided

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am testing overriding with Prestashop 1.6 and i have problem with Smarty. In admin themes file tpl exists function {include file=...}.

In directory override I replace this file and i created file which it has included, but it doesn't read this file from {include file=...}.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which file you are trying to override? and what's the strucutre of your override folder for the files/folders that you added?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override both files, the included file and the file which includes.

In the line where `{include}` is used the path must be:

`{include file='../_current_dir_/_file_.tpl'}`

e.g. you want to override cart rules template:

`override/controllers/admin/templates/cart_rules/informations.tpl`

Then you need the template which includes it. `form.tpl` (in this case):

`override/controllers/admin/templates/cart_rules/form.tpl`

Inside `form.tpl` you need to change `{include}` of `informations.tpl` to:

`{include file='../cart_rules/informations.tpl'}`

Even both templates are in the same level it is for some reason needed to go one level up.